# Request additional permissions only for specific users in Meteor

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have an application allowing users to sign in using their Facebook and Twitter accounts. I only need a very basic information like their email address and full name. Everything works fine and as planned.

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        facebook: ['email'],
        github: ['user:email']
    }
});
```

But, now I need to implement a feature posting to a Facebook page and Twitter on behalf of the admin users only. So, I need to get additional permissions from specific users only.

Admin users are eligible to manage our page at Facebook. The app needs to request additional permissions to be able to post to the page. I wan't to keep those basic permissions for regular users.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is, 
If you know that logged in user is Admin, put the re-authenticate button in user-dashboard (or somewhere which makes sense) that will do authentication user of user for whatever permissions as required by application.

This will basically do, oauth with social service like usual and upon completion you will get aceess code and against this code get the re-newed access token from social service. (This is normal , how you basically do   the oauth manually) Now, use this access token to post to social services.

For this, you will need to use node modules such as for facebook -[fb_graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbgraph) , for twitter- [twiiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was going to do. I'm just curious if bundled accounts* apps from Meteor are able to handle that.